# JavaScript - How to set new instance as parameter, created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, string, oop, object, instance

I have a method which sets a new instance to an array, created dynamically. How can I do that without the use of `eval()`?

```
var Form = (function(){
    function Form(params){
        this.shapesArray = [];
        this.shape;
        ...
    }

    Form.prototype.submit = function(){
        ... this.shape is the shape selected by the user ...
        this.setShape('new Shapes.' + this.shape + '(arg1, arg2, color)');
    }

    Form.prototype.setShape = function(obj){
        this.shapesArray.push(obj);
    }
return Form;
}());
```

So, how to call the `setShape` method by passing `new` instance to it without `eval()`?

This works so far:

```
Form.prototype.submit = function(){
    eval('this.setShape(new Shapes.'+ this.shape.capitalize() +'('+ str_params + '))');
}
```

But using `eval()` is not a good practice. How to achieve the same result wighout `eval()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access the property :

```
this.setShape(new Shapes[this.shape](arg1, arg2, color));
```

Now, if you get your arguments from a dynamic array, it's a little more complex because you can't just use `apply`.

Here's a solution:

```
var constructor = new Shapes[this.shape];
var C = function(){
    return constructor.apply(this, arr_of_args);
}
C.prototype = constructor.prototype;
this.setShape(new C());
```

But this starts to get tricky and hard to read. A new design of your application not involving dynamic constructors having a variable number of arguments might be preferable.

Comment: Thank you. Seems like it's working. How can I pass arguments, if the count of arguments is also dyamically created? How can I manage to use `apply`? Something like `this.setShape(new Shapes[this.shape].apply(null, arr_of_args));`

Comment: @Ezio_ See edit. But I clearly wouldn't use something so complex just to create instances, there's probably a better design for your application (might be a map of factories for example).